# Write a CFG for the language $\{0^n 1^a 2^b \mid n = a+b\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I would like some help for the computation theory.

There is a PDA that accepts the language $\{0^n 1^a 2^b \mid n = a+b\}$, so how can I express it into context free grammar? Any help would be appreciated!

That's what I was trying, I am not sure if it is correct or not

```
S -> 0SA | 0SB | empty
A -> 1
B -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your grammar generates mixed $1$s and $2$s.

You can try something like this:

$S\rightarrow 0SB | S'$
$S' \rightarrow 0S'A | \varepsilon$
$A\rightarrow 1$
$B\rightarrow 2$

Notice that I don't know if in your problem $n$ can be $0$ or not (and similarly for $a$ and $b$), so maybe you have to fix something.

Anyway, here the idea is starting generating first some $0$s an all the $2$s, and then add the remaining $0$s and the $1$s: it is similar to the "standard" grammar used to generate $0^n 1^n$.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: one more thing, can this context free grammar generate any regular lanuage ?
and how should I determine if a context free grammar can generate a regular lanuage?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Any regular language is generated by a CFG, but this specific grammar generates a single language, that is not regular (you van prove it using Pumping Lemma). There's no general algorithm to decide if a CFG actually generates a regular language, i.e., it's an undecidable problem. Anyway, once you have a specific CFG, there's some standard strategies (again, Pumping Lemma) to prove if the generated language is regular. Anyway, this question is interesting, and maybe deserves an other post.

Comment: oh, thank you so much! basically, by using the pumping lemma on the lanuage generated by CFG.  Then, i will be able to see whether this particular CFG could generate a regular lanuage?  thats a good tactic i have not thought about it. thanks for that

Comment: and i just want to clarify one thing: some of the CFG cannot generate the regular lanuage even CFG being more powerful than regular lanuage.

Comment: i come up another idea to prove that if a CFG can generate a regular lanuage:  if i am able to find a regular grammar that generates exactly the same set of lanuage as this CFG.  <--- do u think it is also a option apart from the pumping lemma?

Comment: If you have a PDA or a CFG and you find an equivalent FSA or a regular grammar, then you have done you job. Anyway: a single grammar generates a single language, not a set of languages: a language L is a set of words (or strings) and a grammar G generates L iff it produces all and only the words in L.